# How do I unit test a code that creates and returns a pyspark dataframe using Mock?

Tags: python, unit-testing, pyspark, mocking, pytest

I have the following script which creates a pyspark dataframe and returns it.

get_data.py

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

class Extract():

    def __init__(self,**kwargs):
        self.name=kwargs.get('NAME')

    def get_data(self, count):
        data={"Name": self.name,
                  "Count": count}
        spark = SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate()
        ctrl_data=spark.createDataFrame(data)
        return data
```

test_get_data.py

```
from unittest.mock import MagicMock
from get_data import Extract
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession



def test_get_data():
    
    spark_session_mock = MagicMock(name="SparkSession")
    create_data_frame_mock = MagicMock(name="createDataFrame")

    
    name = "John Doe"
    extract = Extract(NAME=name)
    
    count = 10

    SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate = MagicMock(return_value=spark_session_mock)

    spark_session_mock.createDataFrame = MagicMock(return_value=create_data_frame_mock)

    result = extract.get_data(count)

    expected_data = {"Name": name, "Count": count}
    assert result == expected_data

    SparkSession.builder.getOrCreate.assert_called_once()
    spark_session_mock.createDataFrame.assert_called_once_with([expected_data])
```

I tried writing the above function for unit testing but it fails. What am I doing wrong here? I do not want to use any actual Spark Sessions instead I want to mock all Spark operations.

Comment: The standard way of testing Spark code is by comparing dataframes. In order to create a dataframe you must create a Spark session too. I don't think you can avoid creating a Spark session anyways.

Comment: Can you specify how the test fails?